# Creating Function in SQL

Tags: database, function, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench and trying to create a function that will get as a parameter a date and return it in the format(example) : Monday 1st January 2022.
To do so I created the following code which gives me the error: Truncated incorrect Double value:'st'.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getDate`(getData date) RETURNS varchar(40) CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN DAYNAME(getData) + ' ' + 
+  DAY(getData) +
CASE
WHEN DAY(getData) IN ( 1 , 21 , 31) THEN "st"
WHEN DAY(getData) IN ( 2, 22) THEN "nd"
WHEN DAY(getData) IN (3,23) THEN "rd"
ELSE "th"
END 
+ ' ' +
MONTHNAME(getData) + ' ' 
+ Year(getData);
END
```

Comment: why not using DATE_FORMAT function?

Comment: @ZubairAhmd I have an assigned course project that indicates the creation of a function so I tried this but it's not working.